# MatLab transformPointsForward equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, matplotlib, affinetransform

I need an equivalent function to [transformPointsForward](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/projective2d.transformpointsforward.html) (from MatLab) in Python. I  have a code from: https://github.com/jwyang/face-alignment, which I'm trying to re-write in Python using openCv.

---

I have a following function in MatLab:

```
[pixel_a_x_lmcoord, pixel_a_y_lmcoord] = transformPointsForward(Tr_Data{s}.meanshape2tf{k}, pixel_a_x_imgcoord', pixel_a_y_imgcoord');
```

where

- `Tr_Data{s}.meanshape2tf{k]` is a geometric transformation, specified as an `affine2d` geometric transformation object.
- `pixel_a_x_imgcoors` is vector 1000x1
- `pixel_a_y_imgcoors` is vector 1000x1

---

**My attempts**

I'm searching for an equivalent function, but I'm not succesfull. So far I've found [matplotlib.transform.Affine2D](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D), so I have all the inputs ready.

The problem is, I can't find the forward geometric transform function in Python. I've tried [cv2.perspectiveTransform()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m%29), but it gives me completely different output:

**Example:**

**MatLab**

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 0 0 1]';
pixelx = [1 5 9]';
pixely = [7 5 3]';
obj = affine2d(A);
[x,y] = transformPointsForward(obj,pixelx',pixely');
```

Output:

```
x = [18 18 18]
y = [45 51 57]
```

**Python**

```
A = np.transpose(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,1]], dtype='float32'))
v = np.array([np.transpose(np.array([[1,5,9],[7,5,3]],dtype='float32'))])
cv2.perspectiveTransform(v,A)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0.63043481,  0.80434781],
        [ 0.54347825,  0.76086956],
        [ 0.45652175,  0.71739131]]], dtype=float32)
```

---

#### Edit:

I've tried the transform function, but the output from [cv2.transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transform) is wrong.

Code:

```
A = np.transpose(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,1]], dtype='float32'))
v = np.array([np.transpose(np.array([[1,5,9],[7,5,3]],dtype='float32'))])
cv2.transform(v,A)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 29., 37., 45.], 
        [ 25., 35., 45.], 
        [ 21., 33., 45.]]], dtype=float32)
```

---

#### Edit2:

I've tried to used the matrix without the line `[0,0,1]`, but the result is still incorrect.

Code:

```
A = np.transpose(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype='float32'))
v = np.array([np.transpose(np.array([[1,5,9],[7,5,3]],dtype='float32'))])
cv2.transform(v,A)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 29.,  37.,  45.],
        [ 25.,  35.,  45.],
        [ 21.,  33.,  45.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the transform function, but output from cv2.transform(v,A) is wrong. Output this function is array([[[ 29.,  37.,  45.], [ 25.,  35.,  45.], [ 21.,  33.,  45.]]], dtype=float32). The right output is array([[[18,18,18],[45,51,57]]], dtype=float32).

Comment: You should edit your attempt into the question. I'll have a closer look.

Comment: I've added the info about my next attempt into the question.

Comment: I think those transposes are messing you up. Also, the transformation matrix should be `2x3`, so that `[0,1,1]` row is not needed.

Comment: I guess you mean the row `[0,0,1]`. I tried it now, but the result is unfortunatelly still not correct. The other 'strange' thing is, that the output is matrix `3x3`, but I need to get just two vectors (or two column matrix).

Comment: Yes, I meant `[0,0,1]`. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: And do you have any idea what am I doing wrong now (Edit2 in my question).

Comment: In C++, straight multiplication `A*v` works with `A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `v=[[1,5,9],[7,5,3],[1,1,1]]` but I'm still trying to get `transform` to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need a function from MatLab in Python (or any other language) and it isn't in its native libraries (like here it isn't in `NumPy`), then the best practice is **looking for an equivalent (or, at least, similar) function in Octave**.

E.g. here we're looking for `transformPointsForward` from MatLab. The almost equivalent function in Octave is [tformfwd()](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/default/tree/inst/tformfwd.m).

---

#### Code in Python

A very simple code of geometric forward transformation inspired by `tformfwd` will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np

def forwardAffineTransform(T,v1,v2):
    if v1.shape[1] != 1 or v2.shape[1] != 1:
        print('Vectors must be column-shaped!')
        return
    elif v1.shape[0] != v2.shape[0]:
        print('Vectors must be of equal length!')
        return

    vecSize = v1.shape[0]

    concVec = np.concatenate((v1,v2),axis=1)
    onesVec = np.ones((vecSize,1))

    U = np.concatenate((concVec,onesVec),axis=1)

    retMat = np.dot(U,T[:,0:2])

    return (retMat[:,0].reshape((vecSize,1)), retMat[:,1].reshape((vecSize,1)))

def main():
    v1 = np.array([1,4,9,5,6])
    v1.shape = (v1.shape[0],1)

    v2 = np.array([7,2,6,7,8])
    v2.shape = (v2.shape[0],1)

    T = np.array( [ [1,3,0],[2,2,0],[3,5,1] ] )

    res = forwardAffineTransform(T,v1,v2)

    print("{0}\n{1}".format(res[0], res[1]))


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output:

```
[[ 18.]
 [ 11.]
 [ 24.]
 [ 22.]
 [ 25.]]
[[ 22.]
 [ 21.]
 [ 44.]
 [ 34.]
 [ 39.]]
```

Comment: It's not my input data, but your code is OK. Thanks.